# Puppet hostname doesn't match server certificate

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to set up a Ubuntu VM with puppet installed so I can locally test our production setup.  I'm having trouble getting puppetmaster and puppet to talk to each other.  Let me take you through my steps. (The server's `hostname` is a FQDN of the format "web1.xxx.xxx.net").

So firstly, I clear out all the pem files (except the CA pems of course) from the `/etc/puppet/ssl` directory so I can do a fresh start.  `puppetca --list` returns no results.

Then, I run `puppetd --test` to generate a CSR for the puppetmaster. `puppetca --list` now includes my hostname ("web1.xxx.xxx.net").

Then I run `puppetca --sign web1.xxx.xxx.net`. Now `puppetca --list` is empty again -- everything working fine so far.

Lastly I run `puppetd --test` again.  I get the following output:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: hostname was not match with the server certificate
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Listing the contents of the `/etc/puppet/ssl` directory shows PEM files with the correct server name, which matches my `hostname`. Anyone have any ideas on how to attack this problem?

Answer (score 9):

The error is because the client by default connects to the server hostname 'puppet' but the certificate presented does not have 'puppet' either as its subject or as a SubjectAltName attribute.

To fix it, you can (pick one):

1. instead of initializing your puppetmaster's certificate by running `puppetd`, initialize it by running `puppetmasterd` -- this will cause the cert subject name to include "puppet".
2. instead of leaving things to chance you can use `puppetca --generate --certdnsnames puppet:puppet.mydomain.com web1.xx.xx.xx.net` -- the certdnsnames option specifies a list of SubjectAltNames which will be included in the certificate; it should have a colon-separated list of *any name* that a client would use to contact the server.
3. instead of just running `puppetd --test` on the client, run `puppetd --test --server=web1.xx.xx.xx.net` so the server name the client connects to is one that actually exists in the certificate presented by the server.

Check out masterzen's excellent blog entry for further troubleshooting: [Puppet SSL Explained](http://www.masterzen.fr/2010/11/14/puppet-ssl-explained/)

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the puppetmaster log file? I found the same problem, and found that the server logs the certificate info:

```
[2012-02-28 16:21:09] INFO  
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 2 (0x2)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ca
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 26 16:32:46 2012 GMT
            Not After : Feb 24 16:32:46 2017 GMT
        Subject: CN=ubuntu.localdomain
```

The field Subject shows that the CN is "ubuntu.localdomain", so I executed the puppet by doing:

```
puppetd -t --server=ubuntu.localdomain --fqdn=myfqdn
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Pau answered, I'd just like to highlight that you can inspect the puppetmasters certificate using:

```
openssl x509 -text -in /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/<hostname_of_puppet_master>
```

Then make sure that you use the exact same hostname when from the client:

```
puppetd --server <hostname_of_puppet_master> <etc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are both servers able to resolve each other?
My guess is that since you are VMing it you might be missing the name resolution. If you don't use DNS to let the servers resolve each other you need to add entries to your `/etc/hosts` file on both servers.

Puppet requires the hostnames to resolve to the correct IPs, without this you will get the error you mentioned. You may need to recreate certificates after doing this. **Both machines should be able to ping each by hostname.**

Another thing to be careful of with VMs is that you sync the times on the servers. If you don't it is likely the certificates will be invalid.

Comment: Ah, I should have specified. Puppet and Puppetmaster are both running on the same server; my VM.  And yes, I can ping the computer from itself using the FQDN.

Comment: Sorry Joshua that is incorrect. puppet does not do DNS->IP validation against the certificate presented. It _does_ do hostname to certname validation, which is what's causing the error.